# Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE)

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, window, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I opened an ubuntu virtual machine on gcloud and tried to install GUI(window-user interface) I installed Xfce with

```
 apt-get install xfce4
```

command. But 
i get

> no screens found(EE)

error.I tried "gnome" "KDE" but same result and i don't know why. I searched online and tried everyway as ı know but no success.

The full error is

> current Operating System: Linux instance-5 4.13.0-1008-gcp #11-Ubuntu
>   SMP Thu Jan 25 11:08:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 Kernel command line:
>   BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-1008-gcp
>   root=UUID=b6adc449-5e3d-4331-ba6b-6e99a75fa48e ro
>   scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=Y console=ttyS0 Build Date: 13 October 2017 
>   01:57:05PM xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support
>   please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)  Current version of pixman:
>   0.33.6
>           Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
>           to make sure that you have the latest version. Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
>           (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
>           (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown. (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jan 30 12:24:29 2018
>   (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d" (EE) 
>   Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE)

Why i am getting this error? Is this because of gcloud servers or something else?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present there is no GPU installed on any of the VMs and having a graphical desktop on them is not so straight forward. There is a GPU feature request which you can follow by pressing on the star on [Public Issue Tracker (PIT)](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=14) link.

To be able to have and use a graphical desktop you can configure VNC remote access for your VM as described in the URL links [2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c) and/or [3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Keep in mind that although above link [2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c) or [3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) steps seem to have succeeded, these are third-party websites containing information that isn’t provided by Google and its contents cannot be guaranteed. Also since there is no GPU installed, this installation might fail for high resolution desktop.